# WMHelp XMLPad reliability?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

Why would [WMHelp XMLPad](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/xmlschema-dev/2006Sep/0077.html) fail to validate 3, 5, 7 elements for an XSD that constraints element cardinality via `minOccurs="2"` and `maxOccurs="unbounded"` ?

I have this simple XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="mySchema.xsd">
  <items>
    <item id="1">
      <levels>
        <level>one</level>
      </levels>
    </item>
    <item id="2">
      <levels>
        <level>one</level>
        <level>two</level>
      </levels>
    </item>
    <item id="3">
      <levels>
        <level>one</level>
        <level>two</level>
        <level>three</level>
      </levels>
    </item>
    <item id="4">
      <levels>
        <level>one</level>
        <level>two</level>
        <level>three</level>
        <level>four</level>
      </levels>
    </item>
    <item id="5">
      <levels>
        <level>one</level>
        <level>two</level>
        <level>three</level>
        <level>four</level>
        <level>five</level>
      </levels>
    </item>
  </items>
</root>
```

I want each `<levels>` list to contain at least 2 `<level>` elements. So here is the XSD I wrote:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:complexType name="ItemType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="levels">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="level" type="xs:string" minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="items" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="item" type="ItemType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

When I validate my XML against my XSD in a tool called "WMHelp XMLPad", I get a warning for `<item id="1">`, but also - **unexpectedly!** - for `<item id="3">` and `<item id="5">`. It looks like even counts of `<item>` (2, 4) are OK, but odd ones (1, 3, 5) are rejected.

```
Element levels {} has invalid structure for schema definition: (level{2..unbounded})
```

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps try a different tool, I don't see any problem with your code and sample with two validators other than the `/root/items/item[1]/levels` being reported as invalid due to lack of sufficient `level` children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an odd problem.

Neither I nor my Xerces-based XSD validator see anything wrong with your expectation: Only the number of `<item id="1">` `level` elements violates the XSD:

> `[Error] try.xml:7:16: cvc-complex-type.2.4.i`: The content of element 'levels' is not complete. 'level' is expected to occur a minimum of '2' times. One more instance is required to satisfy this constraint.

There are no other validation errors.

**This appears to be a bug in `WMHelp XMLPad`.**

Follow-up: The original domain (`www.wmhelp.com`, per [this 2006 announcement](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/xmlschema-dev/2006Sep/0077.html)) for `WMHelp XMLPad` is redirecting to sketchy sites, so it's unclear how one would report a bug.

**Conclusion:** `WMHelp XMLPad` is unreliable, unsupported, and should be avoided.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback! Indeed, I've just tried validating my file in Notepad++ (**Plugins -> XML Tools -> Validate now**) and it worked as expected.